# Difficulty ticking checkbox inside BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-intent, baseadapter, android-checkbox

I have a `ListView` with each row consisting of a `TextView` and a `CheckBox`.

The user is allowed to click on each `TextView`, and once he does a Dialog is presented to him where he is expected to either choose Yes or No.

When he chooses Yes, another activity is presented to him where he needs to enter data.

I am implementing all this inside a base adapter class, so inside the base adapter I created the `AlertDialog` and handled it's `OnClickListeners`.

Here is the problem: I need to use `startActivityForResult` in order to get back the data that the user will enter in the new activity, and like I said above, I have done so in the `BaseAdapter`.  Now, how can I get the data from the new activity back inside the `BaseAdapter`?  I researched various sources and found out that one cannot start an Intent directly from a `BaseAdapter` class, but instead needs to reference the Intent to the calling activity like below:

```
((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

This would then result in having the the `onActivityResult()` method in the adapter Activity and not inside the `BaseAdapter`.
I need to leave the code inside the `BaseAdapter` for various reasons.

The value I need to retrieve is a simple `boolean` that if it results to true, will tick the `CheckBox` next to the selected `TextView`.

How could I implement this? What alternatives do you guys suggest?  I tried creating a method inside the `BaseAdapter` so that I can call it from the "main" Activity at the `OnActivityResult()` but the `CheckBox` that I need to tick is returning null at that point; the reason being quite obvious.

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

*Inside BaseAdapter class*

```
       final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("Materials");
        builder.setMessage("Did you require any materials to fix this error?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                String clickedError;
                clickedError = holder.text.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Material.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("materialList", materialList);
                intent.putExtra("clickedError", clickedError);
                intent.putExtra("repairID", repairID);
                ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);            
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                if(checkbox.getTag() == v.getTag())
                {
                    checkbox.setChecked(true);
                }
            }               
        });
        builder.show();

// Method to tick the checkbox.

public void TickBox(CheckBox cb)
{
    cb.setChecked(true);
}
```

*The main activity containing OnActivityResult()*

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {           
        boolean moreThanOne = data.getBooleanExtra("moreThanOne", false);
        if(moreThanOne)
        {
            CheckBox cb = adapter.checkbox;
            adapter.TickBox(cb);
        }
        else
        {
            // ....
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Your onActivityResult method called at where??

Comment: Its inside the activity implementing the base adapter

Comment: I have seen your code i don't understand this line..                   boolean moreThanOne = data.getBooleanExtra("moreThanOne", false);       for this at where you have set putExtra?

Comment: When returning the result for the activity.  Let me explain better.  I have two activities one called Repair and the other Material.  Repair has a listview with a textbox and chackbox as I explained above.  Material is the activity which is triggered when the user clicks Yes from the dialog. I need to pass a boolean result from Material to Repair.  True if the user entered any data.  Now,  since all my code is in the BaseAdapter ( for the listView in Repair) I cannot pass this boolean value to it.

Comment: Since onActivityResult() (the method where the boolean value is recieved) is in Repair.java  and NOT in BaseAdapter.  I need it inside the base adapter.

Comment: Ok...so by default which value set for boolean in putExtra?? True or False??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35900/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-claireg)

Comment: Therefore, to answer your question; I implemented putExtra("booleanValue", booleanValue) inside Material.java when setting the result for the intent.

Comment: The default is false that is why I put  `(boolean moreThanOne = data.getBooleanExtra("moreThanOne", false);)` false in this line.  But of course if it has true than true will be passed instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

u can update ur checkbox from ur activity.... TRY this

when user click the listview send the listItem position to ur new activity.AND return the same value in ur old activity in onActivityResult.

then in onActivityResult **

use the same layout  that u r using when creating listView

```
RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)mListViewObject.getChildAt(i);
                   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                   cb.setChecked(RESULT);
```

Comment: i the position of ur listview item clicked. send this position from your adapter class to ur new actvity via intent and retreive the same value in ur old activity in onActvityResult method.

Comment: But I can't get the position of the listview from the onActivityResult... because it's in a different class and when I try to send it anyway it returns null.

Comment: retreive the position when you touch the text view. then along with the intent of startActivityForResult send the position to ur new activity then send that position back from ur new activity to ur old activity .U can use intent.putExtra from adapter to new activity and from new activity to old activity

Comment: Hmm I haven't thought about this.  I will give it a try now.

Comment: I did so but am having trouble retrieving the checkbox with the position from the old activity

Comment: can you tell what is the trouble ??

Comment: No.  I am currently trying to set the checkbox to checked from the Old activity.  I have its tag saved.  I'm trying something like: `adapter.holder.chk.setChecked(true);` but I don't know where to pass it's tag.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Callback listener inside your BaseAdaper, inside that method write Intent code,

For updating it later Create a method inside the BaseAdapter which will gets called from onActivityResult.

Comment: I didn't quite understand. Could you provide an example?